# How do I use my full Windows 10 account in the regular desktop app?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I bought the full version of Minecraft in the Windows 10 app for my kids a while back... and now my daughter wants to try coding Minecraft.  I downloaded and installed the desktop version of Minecraft, but don't have a Mojang account.. only a Microsoft account.  Is there any way at all to use that same account on the desktop app?  I don't want to pay again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade! Can you clarify the 'Desktop' version of Minecraft? There are a few versions available, with two available for the PC. Bedrock version, bought from the Microsoft store, and the Java version, available from Mojang.com. The accounts are not shareable between the two versions.

Comment: From what I understand, they purchased the Bedrock version for their kids and want to use their account on the Java version.

Comment: If you buy the Java Edition, you get Bedrock edition for free, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that if you want Minecraft Java edition, that you'll be paying full price for it.

As of 19 October 2018, Minecraft Bedrock edition (windows 10 app) and Minecraft Java edition ("desktop version") must be purchased separately. Details can be found here:

https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2064007-minecraft-for-windows-10

Prior to October 19, if you bought Java edition, you could get a redemption code for Bedrock edition. Unfortunately, it doesn't work the other way around.